# how can i do import of d3-selection-multi in typescript

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have installed the package from `d3.js` and `d3-selection-multi`. In my `app/app.component.ts` file I try to import them.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3SelectionMulti from 'd3-selection-multi';
```

My idea is to use the `.attrs` attribute that embeds but I get this error:

```
.attrs is not a function
```

this is my code:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3SelectionMulti from 'd3-selection-multi';
.
.
  var duration = 5000;
  var posicionFinal = 250;
  var posicionActual = 0;
  var segundosDuracion = 0;
  var oProperties = { x: posicionFinal, fill: "red" };
  rectangle
    .datum(oProperties)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attrs(oProperties)
```

how can I solve that?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-angular-wusbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: this may be helpful. [issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/issues/17#issuecomment-383961412)

Comment: It does not work for me, in the live code the package is installed, I try to do what your answer says and I keep getting the same error, or I don't know if I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to import `d3-selection-multi` package in this way as its import is not supported in this manner.

There are multiple alternatives your can use:

1. Replace use of `attrs` with multiple `attr` calls
2. Update your config file to include required scripts during build. For example, in you config json file, update `scripts` section to include following scripts:

```
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/d3-color/dist/d3-color.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-dispatch/dist/d3-dispatch.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-ease/dist/d3-ease.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-interpolate/dist/d3-interpolate.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-selection/dist/d3-selection.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-selection-multi/build/d3-selection-multi.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-timer/dist/d3-timer.min.js",
  "./node_modules/d3-transition/dist/d3-transition.min.js"
]
```

working example can be found at: https://github.com/dipen08it419/D3Test

3. Include required scripts in `index.html` file and use `d3` directly in your component without importing `d3`.

   ```js
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     name = 'Angular 6';
     ngOnInit() {
       var svg = d3
         .select("#video_container")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("width", 1000)
         .attr("height", 1000);

       var rectangle = svg
         .append("rect")
         .attr("width", 100)
         .attr("height", 70)
         .attr("x", 0)
         .attr("y", 50)
         .attr("fill", "blue")
         .attr("opacity", "1");

       var duration = 5000;
       var posicionFinal = 250;
       var posicionActual = 0;
       var segundosDuracion = 0;
       var oProperties = { x: posicionFinal, fill: "red" };

   rectangle
       .datum(oProperties)
       .transition()
       .duration(duration)
       .ease(d3.easeLinear)
       .attrs(oProperties)
     }  
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-color/dist/d3-color.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-dispatch/dist/d3-dispatch.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-ease/dist/d3-ease.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-interpolate/dist/d3-interpolate.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-selection/dist/d3-selection.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-timer/dist/d3-timer.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-transition/dist/d3-transition.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/d3-selection-multi/build/d3-selection-multi.min.js"></script>
   <my-app>loading</my-app>
   ```

as used in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-angular-xukg5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). but use it with caution as you will need to allow node_modules files to be accessible from your setup, which works fine on stackblitz but might not work on your local environment.

Unfortunately due to limited webpack support in the library, we need to take one of these approaches.

Comment: In any of your solutions it appears in typescript that d3 is not defined. also happens in your example

Comment: @yavg Wait are you getting wrror in console of just hightlightling in editor?

Comment: @yavg that happens on the stackblitz only, I believe on your environment it would work not all feature of dev environment are supported by stackblitz, also in the same app if you change any file line, it works as expected.

Comment: In my real project I am getting same problem

Comment: @yavg Take a look at this repo with working code: https://github.com/dipen08it419/D3Test

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a clean way to do with Angular / webpack so I created a type safe helper function that allows chaining.

```
import { BaseType, Selection } from 'd3-selection';
export const multiAttr =
      <GElement extends BaseType, Datum, PElement extends BaseType, PDatum>
      (selection: Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>, attrs: object): Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum> => {
        Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key) => {
          selection.attr(key, attrs[key]);
        });
        return selection;
      };
```

Usage:

```
 multiAttr(
      multiAttr(this.svg.append('defs').append('marker'),
        {
          id: 'hover-arrow',
          viewBox: '-0 -5 10 10',
          refX: 13,
          refY: 0,
          orient: 'auto',
          markerWidth: 13,
          markerHeight: 13,
          xoverflow: 'visible'
        }
      )
        .append('svg:path')
        .style('stroke', 'none'),
      {
        d: 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5',
        fill: '#999'
      }
    );
```